# How to delete logs on Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

I misconfigured a deployment to GAE (the 'Flexible' varient), and let it run for a couple of weeks. I had NOT made a route for _ah/health and it got pinged every four seconds by the GAE infra - causing exceptions to hit the logs courtesy of the web framework. Logs filled to 35GB which is where they sit today, after I made a route for the underdocumented healthcheck route. I can't find anything in the UI to allow me to delete those logs.

https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/ is the main place for viewing logs, but there's no clue within as to how to delete them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK there is no way to delete them - they'll be automatically deleted as they age, depending on your logging service tier's retaining policy:

- Basic Tier: 7-day
- Premium Tier: 30-day

See [Service tiers](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/pricing#service_tiers) for details.

Comment: There's a CLI way of deleting logs it seems. It doesn't give much feedback though and the command is long.  I kinda wish too that https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/ was prominent in more than one left-hand menu thingamy.

Answer (score 7):

There is now a way to do this via the CLI:

`gcloud logging logs delete log-name`

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/logging/logs/delete

Answer (score 4):

You can delete app engine logs using the api.
See https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/projects.logs/delete for details, but there's also a "try this API" section on the right to actually execute it.

Pass in a `logName` something like: `"projects/[PROJECT_ID]/logs/appengine.googleapis.com%2Frequest_log"`

You can also just list the logs with this endpoint: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/projects.logs/list